# Is there any way to get number of invalid attempt of password from membership api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I need to check how many invalid attempt a user taken at the time of log in.

This is becauase our requirement is to save the max attempt password value from db not config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Membership API doesn't expose the invalid attempt counts, but they are indeed tracked in the database.

If you take a look at the documentation for the [Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa(v=vs.100).aspx) you'll see the following in the Database schema section:

```
FailedPasswordAttemptCount Integer,
FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart DateTime,
FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount Integer,
FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart DateTime
```

These work in conjunction with the `PasswordAttemptWindow` setting to lock users out if they fail to supply the correct values, and the counts are updated by the default provider when the user fails to log in.

If you want to manage these through a database rather than the web.config you only really have one choice: Write a custom membership provider (based on the [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75(v=vs.100).aspx)) that reads the required values from the DB rather than the config settings.

This is because the property on the provider is read-only so you can't modify it once the provider is loaded and instantiated.